# The user specified as a definer (''@'') does not exist

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I restored my database but I got this error:

```
The user specified as a definer (''@'') does not exist
```

above message copy/paste from my error.

my MariaDb version:

```
Server version: 10.3.20-MariaDB MariaDB Server
```

I googled but all questions mentioned a `user` inside erorr but my error is just `''@''`.

Comment: Can you provide context? What command were you running when you got that error? Was the error preceded by other messages? Is the error linked to some specific SQL code?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález for `Views` I got this error.

Comment: If you know the name of the affected view, launch your favourite client and run a [SHOW CREATE VIEW](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-create-view/) to see the source code.

Comment: I have the same issue exactly.